# swift segue from tableView through a navigationController to a TableViewController

Tags: swift, tableview, row, segue

I cannot get this to segue to another TableViewController. I keep getting a crash... I know it is because it is going through the NavigationController and I do not know how to segue from the main controller to pass it and go to the tableView. Heres the look
[image]

the segue from the navControl to the tableView is called "ChildsInfo"

[image]

Here is what I am trying and crashing.

```
class PagesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var pagesTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var infoProgressBar: UIProgressView!


    let pages = ["Page 1","Page 2","Page 3"]
    var myIndex = 0

    var selectedPage: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pagesTableView.dataSource = self
        pagesTableView.delegate = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}

extension PagesViewController: UITableViewDataSource {


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "pagesTableViewCell")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = pages[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }



    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pages.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return 71.0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "ChildsInfo", sender: self)

        }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the images you have posted I'm assuming the crash you are getting is that the segue is not found.  This is because you should be trying to perform the segue to the navigation controller itself from the table view (i.e. the link on the left in your image).  The navigation controller then has a root view controller and you can push others onto the stack as required.

Comment: I tried pushing it to the navigation controller. when I click the row it just comes out as a black screen. I can't figure out how to push it to the nav then to the tableview

Comment: Have you created a 'root view' segue between the navigation controller and the table view controller you want inside it?  I'm guessing not as it appears to be a 'show' segue.

Comment: So you have multiple rows in the original table and each of them is to go to a different table view controller (embedded in a navigation controller) right?

Comment: Well the two basic methods you could use are: 1) Create separate UINavigationControllers with UITableViewControllers as the root for each one and call the appropriate segue.  2) Create a single UINavigationController and separate UITableViewControllers, link to the first one (just to set it up) and then override the 'func prepare(for: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)' in the source controller and set the UINavigationController root view controller appropriately.